# POST 401 (Unauthorized) when calling an ajax request in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-8

I want to populate data and show it on the browser when a user selects a value it shows a value based on the value selected on the dropdown.when a user selects a size value, the price for the specific size shows on the browser.i am using jquery ajax to create the function.i have set an alert test when the size is selected else return an error..the issue is it return an error and it doesn't show alert the sizes.also on the console at the browser it shows an error "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/getproductprice 401 (Unauthorized)"..how can I solve this.
here is my jquery script code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers:{
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getprice').change(function(){
        var productsize=$(this).val();
        if(productsize==""){
            alert("please Select size");
            return false;
        }
        var product_id=$(this).attr("product-id");
        // alert(product_id);
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/getproductprice',
            data:{productsize:productsize,product_id:product_id},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(resp){
                alert(resp);
                // $(".getattrprice").html("Sh."+resp);
            },error:function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

here is my getproductprice method in the method_controller

```
public function getproductprice(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $data=$request->all();
            echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die;
            $getproductprice=Productattribute::where(['product_id'=>$data['product_id'],'productattr_size'=>$data['productattr_size']])->first();
            echo $getproductprice->productattr_price;
        }

        return redirect('admin/merchadise')->with('success','The Merchaise has been created succesfully');
    }
```

here's my route

```
Route::post('/getproductprice', [Merchadise_controller::class,'getproductprice'])->name('getproductprice');
```

Comment: Are you sure this route is not protected by auth middleware?

Comment: @muhamadhhassan its protected

Comment: And how do you authenticate your API? Do you use JWT or sanctum?

Comment: am using json web tokens

Answer (score 0):

i figured out where the issue was..i changed the method to another controller that isn't auth protected..also I had an error in the method I changed to this

```
public function getproductprice(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $data=$request->all();
            echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die;
            $getproductprice=Productattribute::where(['product_id'=>$data['product_id'],'productattr_size'=>$data['productattr_size']])->first();
            echo $getproductprice->productattr_price;
        }
     }
```